# Retrieve the value from the barcode scanner in the key event in power builder 12.5

Tags: barcode-scanner, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc, powerbuilder-conversion

I cannot interpret the value from the Barcode Scanner from Power Builder.
I am seeing from Key event, the value of Key seems to be "KeyEscape!" and hence it closes the window.
Is there any syntax which gets the value from the Barcode Scanner in the keyevent ?

But when i use notepad, it is showing some value like "b000012300 " and the space represents KeyEscape!
Is there a way to interpret this value in power builder ?
Please help me.

Comment: Why do you have code in the Key event?  A barcode scanner simply translates a graphic image into a series of keystrokes.  This is why you see what you see in notepad and only see a single keystroke in the Key event.

Answer (score 0):

The `cancel` property for a `CommandButton`, `PictureButton` or `OLECustomControl` makes it being activated by the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

It is likely that you have a button on your window to close it that have the `cancel` property set to `true`.