# Event ID for Capturing the Escape Key from Barcode Scanner

Tags: powerbuilder

I am using PowerBuilder 12.5 .
Please suggest me an Event ID to Capture the Escape Key from Barcode Scanner device connected through USB port.

Comment: What type of barcode are you scanning?

Comment: This is your third question regarding your barcode scanning problem. You were asked some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948861/retrieve-the-value-from-the-barcode-scanner-in-the-key-event-in-power-builder-12) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148584/is-there-a-way-to-differentiate-from-barcode-scanner-entry-from-keyboard-key-pre) but never returns feedback... I told you that the closing of your window could come from a `cancel` property of a button. Did you checked that? You were also told that the scanner only emulates a keyboard, ESC indicating EOL.

Comment: If anyway you need some character filtering, you can do that in the `key()` event of the window, or a `pbm_dwnkey` mapped event of a datawindow. But I guess that your problem is coming from a `cancel` property somewhere.